# Is there a closed form for $\zeta(\pi)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form, riemann-zeta, pi

What is $\zeta(\pi)$?

I know that $\operatorname{Re}(\pi)>1$, thus 
$$\zeta(\pi)=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{n^\pi}$$
Yet I have no idea how to even *begin* evaluating this series. It's probably unrealistic to think that there even *is* a closed form, but math can be funny that way sometimes.

**Edit:** for those of you who are confused about the definition of closed form, here's an example: $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$. Note that this is purely a ration of two constants, and even though $\pi$ cannot be exactly calculated in a finite number of operations, I am still willing to consider it a closed form. Another example: $$_3F_2\biggr(1,1,\frac{3}{2};\frac{4}{3},\frac{5}{3};\frac{2}{27}\biggl)=\frac{3\pi}{5}-\frac{6\log2}{5}$$
Note that, again, there are constants which require infinite operations to compute, yet if we just see them as constants, there is a finite number of operations in the answer, which is good enough for me. It should be noted that I do not consider a decimal expansion an adequate closed form.

Comment: "$\zeta(\pi)$" is most likely the closest you can get to a closed form.

Comment: $\zeta(\pi)=1.1762417383825827588721504519380520912...$ It is "close" to $\zeta(3)=1.2020569031595942853997381615114499908$.

Comment: @Wojowu I fear that may be the case...

Comment: Not necessarily. $\zeta(3)$ also has some nice expressions. Of course, I don't know what do you mean by "closed form".

Comment: @DietrichBurde $$\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$ Is a closed form. No decimals.

Comment: ${\displaystyle \zeta (3)={\frac {5}{2}}\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac {(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{3}{\binom {2n}{n}}}}.}$ is closed form. No decimals.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I should've elaborated. Wikipedia puts it perfectly: "a closed-form expression is a mathematical expression that can be evaluated in a finite number of operations". AKA no integrals, summations, products... I'll edit my question.

Comment: $\pi$ cannot be evaluated in a finite number of operations. So $\pi^2/6$ is not in a closed form. See [here](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-closed-form-expression-for-pi):"Of course there isn’t any closed-form expression for any transcendental number including 
, since it is associated with unreal number called infinity by definition"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84755/discussion-between-clathratus-and-dietrich-burde).

Comment: Is there any closed form (in terms of elementary constant) of any zeta function? Not  considering the positive even integers.

Comment: @Dahaka Look at this: http://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/Zeta/03/02/

Comment: If $\zeta(3)$ doesn't even have a closed form, why do you expect $\zeta(\pi)$ to have one?  Indeed, "most" generic mathematical constants do not have a closed form.

Comment: @JavaMan There are a lot of really neat tricks that mathematicians can employ to find difficult things. And sometimes the irrationality/transcendental-ity of a number doesn't make it harder to deal with. Example: $\sin(3)$ has no closed forms (I think), yet $\sin(\pi)=0$.

Comment: (1) The OP's definition of closed form (including the Wikipedia quote) is not very clear to me. (2) Why would $\zeta( \pi)$ have any kind of closed form except for $\zeta ( \pi) $? There doesn't seem to be any indication of that

Comment: @YuriyS (1)see the new edit on the question (2) why *wouldn't* $\zeta(\pi)$ have any closed forms? For all we know, it could, but we just don't know what they are yet. MSE isn't specifically for questions that have a known answer: it is not a bad question because no-one so far has given an answer.

Comment: @clathratus It is not hard to see why most series don't have a closed form. Here you don't have any clue supporting that $\zeta(\pi)$ could have a closed form, so...

Comment: $\zeta(\pi)$ IS closed-form. If you allow logarithm, why do not you allow $\zeta(x)$? Also, $\zeta(\pi)$ is a constant, not worse than $\pi$.

Comment: While both **e** and $\pi$ depend on polynomial expressions of the type $x^2\pm y^2=r^2,~$ they themselves are **not** meant to be passed as exponent, which is what the [Riemann $\zeta$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) basically does with its argument. After all, the [superellipses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse) $x^a\pm y^a=r^a,~$ with $a\in\{e,\pi\},~$ do not themselves yield any noteworthy constants either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Number theory currently has insufficient tools do deal with this kind of problem. We don't even have a closed form for $\zeta(3)$.